# Connect to SQL Server from cygwin window times out, from DOS prompt works

Tags: sql-server, cygwin, sqlcmd

I can connect to my SQL Server database via sqlcmd from a DOS command window, but not from a Cygwin window. From DOS:

```
F:\Cygnus>sqlcmd -Q "select 'a test'" -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```

---

a test

(1 rows affected)

```
F:\Cygnus>
```

====================================================

From Cygwin:

```
$ sqlcmd -Q "select 'a test'" -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```

> HResult 0x35, Level 16, State 1
>  Named Pipes Provider: Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server [53]. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL
>   Native Client : An error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be
>   caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not
>   allow remote connections.. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client
>   : Login timeout expired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The backslash is being eaten by cygwin's bash shell.  Try doubling it:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select 'a test'" -S .\\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: Duh. That was it... been away from *nix too long. Thanks!

Comment: Duh, alright. I spent about 2 hours trying to workout what the .... was wrong with my new SQL-SERVER 2008 R2 EXPRESS installation, and it turns out that my brain was just operating in MS-compatibility mode within a *nix shell. Doh! Doh! Doh! and DOH! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to allow remote connections for this, and give the full server name i.e SERVER\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass query/instruction to db and receive output in shell if you use "-Q" switch:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select * from nice.dbo.TableName ac ORDER BY 1 DESC" -S server_name\\db_name
```